# Стили input для iPad

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, ipad

Safari на iPad применяет свои стили для отображения `input` с типом `submit`. Что можно сделать, чтобы применялись стили, прописанные в `css`?

Comment: sabmit или все же submit?
как вариант использовать `!important` для повышения приоритета конкретного свойства.

Comment: submit конечно, описалась.

В данном случае помогло свойство css -webkit-appearance со значением none для проблемного элемента.

Также можно использовать стили специально для ipad

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)
and (orientation:portrait) { 
/*стили*/
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)
and (orientation:landscape) { 
/*стили*/
}

Answer (score 1):

Обнулите стили с помощью такой комбинации:

```
[type=submit] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```